# Failed to authenticate with mechanism MONGODB-CR AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

When i have to connect remote database in Mongodb getting error on log using robomongo database.

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

2015-10-03T00:29:51.275-0500 I ACCESS   [conn25] Failed to authenticate sa@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document. The following details are,

User name:
password : 
port : 
database name : 
IP address :

How t

Comment: This is a known issue. Robomongo 0.8.x is not fully compatible with MongoDB 3.0 and does not support the new default SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766. You may want to look for an alternative admin GUI: see http://mongodb-tools.com, "GUI" purpose category.

Comment: Thanks, i got solution and shared in stack overflow, [mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287642/mongo-3-0-5-unable-to-connect-from-external-client)